# c++: How distant(in bytes) are class member in an array?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I found no better way to formulate my question like this:
Is the output below always true? is this portable?

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

//...
std::vector<Point> points(3);
unsigned char* start = (unsigned char*)(&points[0]);
unsigned char* end = (unsigned char*)(&points[1]); 

std::cout << "is this the same ? " << std::distance(start,end) == sizeof(Point);
```

What if instead of a `vector`, `points` were defined as a raw array? Is the output still always true?

```
Point *points = new Point[3]; // instead of std::vector<Point> points(3);
```

Comment: Yes. At least, a vector is guaranteed to be stored in memory as a normal C array.

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed to be stored as an array. [edit] ah Erik beat me to it :-)

Comment: _"All comments contained something like..."_ Yes, because that's what you asked about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `std::vector`, [vector.overview]/1 (N3337) says:

> The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

So yes, your program's behaviour is portable and well-defined.

For arrays, [dcl.array]/1 states:

> An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty set of `N` subobjects of type `T`.

This is not quite so explicit as the `vector` quote, but the co-usage of the word "contiguous" points to the fact that the `std::vector` storage identity also applies to arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one of the requirement for the vector is that its elements must be store contiguously.

From n2798:

> 23.2.6 Class template vector [vector]
>
> > 1 A vector is a sequence container that supports random access
> >     iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized) constant time insert
> >     and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take
> >     linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints
> >     can be given to improve efficiency. The elements of a vector are
> >     stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some
> >     type other than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n
> >     for all 0 <= n < v.size().

Comment: @user1235183 do you mean `Point* points = new Points[3];`? In that case, yes.

Comment: yes i menat it. And your yes means it is well defined, portable and correct.

Comment: @user1235183 Indeed, see the quote from [dcl.array] in my answer.